# Access Denied error after setting up MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

> Access is denied.
>
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required
>   to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to
>   the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration. Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server. Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.
>   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET > Version:4.0.30319.18010

I followed the simple tutorial from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4), ran the application and received this message.

Comment: What is the hosting environment? I mean do you  have the access to the file system? or you are on a shared host, or you are debugging you application using visual studio directly?

Comment: Try to open VS as Administrator.  Did you set up IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: I am debugging it using visual studio directly and yes i tried open VS as administrator too

Comment: which VS and windows version you are using?

Comment: visual studio 2012 Ultimate RC and windows 8

Answer (score 38):

Check your project properties and ensure that Anonymous Authentication = **Enabled**.  If you have `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your web.config, you will also need to set Windows Authentication = **Enabled** for the project (click the project in Solution Explorer):

[image: Properties]

The effect this has is to change the project file (.csproj) from saying:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
```

To:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```

So you can also do this by hand, or fix it permanently by modifying the intranet project template.

Comment: The first item (Anonymous Auth ) was set but the second item (Windows Auth ) wasn't.  I enabled Windows Auth and it worked after that. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure you run Visual Studio as Admin. This along with the solution above resolved the same for me

Answer (score 2):

So I just wanted to chime in on something that worked for me.  I created a new "ASP.Net MCV 4 Web application" and used the  "Intranet Application" project template.  I had to enable "Windows Authentication".  I assume this is because I chose the *intranet* application template versus the *internet* application template.

Answer (score 2):

**Basically first allow users or rolse access**

Default web.config denies access

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

so make sure you allow yourself

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="domain\User" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Issue today while building the app in Visual studio. The project file was somehow corrupted. Not allowing to do anything (modiyfying web.config file). Closed everything and re-opened. It worked with same config before
Anonymous Authentication=Enabled
Windows Authentication=Disabled.